# How i can get my database host name for my android php file?

Tags: php, mysql, web-services, phpmyadmin, cpanel

After i knew how to import my database to phpMyAdmin and how to upload php files to file manager i wanna know how to get my host name to insert and delete from database in phpMyAdmin

```
<?php  $json =file_get_contents('php://input');

$con = mysqli_connect("hostname","username","password");

if (!$con) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());

}else{

    mysql_select_db('royal_sharm_property', $con); }

$sql = "SET character_set_results = 'utf8', character_set_client = 'utf8', character_set_connection = 'utf8', character_set_database = 'utf8', character_set_server = 'utf8'";

mysqli_query($con, $sql) ;

$data  = json_decode($json,true); ?>
```

Now, how can i get my host name?

[image]

Note: i don't have website, i have android app only

Comment: Didn't receive any Email including hosting details from your provider?

Comment: @BanujanBalendrakumar No, how can i get it?

Comment: You will get automatically, When you complete the `account&payment ` The processes are different depends on the hosting provider. The simple way is contact them via `Live-Chat` or `Creating Tickets` in your dashboard

Comment: i've already finished everything but it was long time ago, so how get my host name from godady or cpanal?

Comment: I can't say directly. Bcoz there is 2 types of hosting `1.shared hosting` & `2. Dedicated Hosting`... If your host is shared, Then you can't access it by IP.. Because, many users may sharing the Host with you. The only way is buy a Domain. If your hosting is dedicated, Then you can use the IP as host. To get better solution reach your hosting provider

Comment: Okay, thank you for your help.